# Data is there but cannot display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a JSON function to return the following data and it is what I expected:

```
[{"ShowId":1,"Title":"The Forresters Axe","Date":"\/Date(1339714800000)\/","Time":{"Hours":19,"Minutes":0,"Seconds":0,"Milliseconds":0,"Ticks":684000000000,"Days":0,"TotalDays":0.79166666666666663,"TotalHours":19,"TotalMilliseconds":68400000,"TotalMinutes":1140,"TotalSeconds":68400}}]
```

but when I try to display the Title on the view page I am having problems. This is the view page code:

```
<table> @foreach (var showList in Model) {<tr><td>@showList.Title</td></tr>}<.table>
```

This is the ActionResult I have been using but when I got through to the view I could not get the data to display. I used the JSON function as above to double check that I had the right data and was not trying to call something that was not there.

```
enter/*-------------------------------------------------------
      BOOKING/CHECKAVAIL ACTIONRESULT CALLING CHECKAVAIL VIEW
        Select information from Run table where the id == ShowId

     ------------------------------------------------------*/
    public ActionResult CheckAvail(int id)
    {
        var showList = from r in db.Runs
                       join s in db.Shows on r.ShowId equals s.ShowId
                       where r.ShowId == id
                       select new
                     {
                         ShowId = r.ShowId,
                         Title = s.Title,
                         Date = r.Date,
                         Time = r.Time
                     };
        return View(showList);
    }
```

The error I get is:

RuntimeBinderException was unhandled by code

'object' does not contain a definition for Title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the expression `new { ... }` you are creating an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) which is basically not supported to pass in the `View` method as a Model.

There are a few workarounds:

- [Anonymous View Models in ASP.NET MVC Using Dynamics](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/09/anonymous-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dynamics/)
- [Passing anonymous type to ASP.NET MVC's View](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/03/passing-anonymous-type-to-aspnet-mvcs.html)

But the easiest solution is to create a viewmodel which will hold your data:

```
public class CheckAvailViewModel
{
    public int ShowId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

And return this from your query:

```
var showList = from r in db.Runs
                     // ...
                     select new CheckAvailViewModel
                     {
                         ShowId = r.ShowId,
                         Title = s.Title,
                         Date = r.Date,
                         Time = r.Time
                     };
return View(showList.ToArray());
```